# Multiple post type queries (with specific arguments for each)

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, query-posts, post-type

So i know how to combine post types into 1 loop and out put the loop. Below is what i have:

```
        <?php

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => array('post','movie','actor'),
            'posts_per_page' => '20',
        );

        query_posts( $args );
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

            the_title();

        endwhile; 

        ?>
```

This works as expected, however is it possible to specify different arguments for each post type, while keeping them within the same original loop.

So for example i need to add a `meta_key=value` argument to the `movie` & `actor` post types. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you do something like this?

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array('post','movie','actor'),
        'posts_per_page' => '20',
    );

    query_posts( $args );
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

        global $post;

        if (($post_type == 'movie') && (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_key', true) == 'your-value')) {

             // Display your content for Movie Post Type with meta value set

         } else if (($post_type == 'actor') && (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_key', true) == 'your-other-value')) {     

             // Display your content for Actor Post Type and Other Meta Value

         }    

    endwhile; 

    ?>
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. Yes currently this is the only way i've figured out around the problem. However, this messes up the `posts_per_page` argument in the original query due to not every post having the specific meta values. But this may have to do :/